# opengl 4.3 compute shader not writing value to buffer

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, compute-shader

I am having a weird problem with compute shaders since I changed the structure size of a buffer I was passing in to the shader.

```
struct Particle
{
    vec3 position;
    vec2 uv;
    vec3 accumulated_normal;
    int id;
    int flattened_id;
    int movable;
    // can the particle move or not ? used to pin parts of the cloth
    float mass;
    // the mass of the particle (is always 1 in this example)
    vec3 old_pos;
    // the position of the particle in the previous time step, used as part of the verlet numerical integration scheme
    vec3 acceleration;
    // a vector representing the current acceleration of the particle
};
```

Defined like this. I was having problems trying to use the flattened id so I wanted to write the id's back to the buffer I was passing in. The shader looks something like this.

```
layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    unsigned int flattened_id = gl_LocalInvocationIndex;

    particleBuffer.particles[0].id = 16;
    particleBuffer.particles[1].id = 17;
    particleBuffer.particles[2].id = 18;
    particleBuffer.particles[3].id = 19;
    //particleBuffer.particles[4].id = 20;
}
```

So till this point it is fine but the moment I uncomment the last line which is the particleBuffer.particles[4], the mesh vanishes from the screen. I have managed to change the position data from this mesh before but this seems strange. I verified that I have indeed 16 elements of the buffer which I am passing in so it should not go out of bounds either (i.e. cloth1.particles.size() = 16). Any ideas ?? 
The entire code is here..
https://github.com/ssarangi/OpenGL_Cloth/tree/master/cloth_4_3_compute

```
glUseProgram(computeShader);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, cloth1.particles.size() * sizeof(Particle), &(cloth1.particles[0]), GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);

glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);

{
    GLenum err = gl3wGetError();
}

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage);
Particle * ptr = reinterpret_cast<Particle *>(glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, cloth1.particles.size() * sizeof(Particle), GL_MAP_READ_BIT));

memcpy(&cloth1.particles[0], ptr, cloth1.particles.size()*sizeof(Particle));
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

*************************** EDITED with Andon's comments **********************************
This is the new layout from the C++ side.

```
struct Particle
{
    vec4 position;
    vec2 uv;
    vec4 accumulated_normal;
    vec4 old_pos; // the position of the particle in the previous time step, used as part of the verlet numerical integration scheme
    vec4 acceleration; // a vector representing the current acceleration of the particle
    int id;
    int flattened_id;
    int movable; // can the particle move or not ? used to pin parts of the cloth
    float mass; // the mass of the particle (is always 1 in this example)
```

The GLSL side definition. What I am unsure about is if the padding elements need to be included in the glsl structure or not. It still doesn't update the ID's.

```
struct Particle
{
    vec4 position;
    vec2 uv;
    vec4 accumulated_normal;
    vec4 old_pos; // the position of the particle in the previous time step, used as part of the verlet numerical integration scheme
    vec4 acceleration; // a vector representing the current acceleration of the particle
    int id;
    int flattened_id;
    int movable; // can the particle move or not ? used to pin parts of the cloth
    float mass; // the mass of the particle (is always 1 in this example)
};
```

Comment: Where is `particleBuffer` defined in your GLSL shader? You have a ***lot*** of potential alignment issues in your struct. With your current misaligned data structure, the output of `id` is probably being stored in your C struct's `old_pos.x` member. +1 unit of padding between `position` and `uv`, +2 units between `uv` and `accumulated_normal` and +1 between `accumulated_normal` and `id`. Overall the structure is off by 4 whole machine units by the time you get around to `id`.

Comment: After looking at the git code listing, I am pretty sure this is exactly your problem. You are using a `std430` layout, but not following any of the necessary alignment rules that come with that layout. You also need 1-float worth of padding between `old_pos` and `acceleration`.

Comment: Thanks Andon, I edited the question again with the new layout. However, it still doesn't update the id.

Comment: So from std430, vec2 are twice the size of underlying scalar type. So I shouldn't need a padding between my vec2 uv & vec3 accumulated_normal right ?

Comment: No, you need padding because the base alignment (boundary that it must begin on) of a 3-component vector type in GLSL is **4**. 3-component anything is a bunch of smoke and mirrors in GL. If it's not **1**, **2** or **4**, it's generally a trick the API is pulling on you ;) To put this another way, `vec3` has the same storage characteristics of `vec4`... just as `GL_RGB8` usually becomes `GL_RGBA8` when the driver works with it, to avoid 3-byte alignment issues.

Comment: Correct, I agree with you. But if you look at the first element, its a vec4 position, vec2 uv following that and then again a vec4 accumulated_normal. Which means, they are all aligned to a 8 byte boundary. Anyways I tried making the uv also a vec4 but that also didn't solve anything yet. I even tried to change position but that also surprisingly doesn't seem to get reflected anymore.

Comment: Well, in addition to all that, I think you may need a memory barrier for the result of the compute shader to be visible.

Comment: well in this case, since the values written to the shader is a constant, we don't need a memory barrier isn't it ? Had it been dependent data, then a memory barrier is required. However, am still confused as to why fixing the alignment is still not causing it update any data on the buffer.. :(

Comment: I don't mean a barrier in the shader itself. I mean one at the command level (`glMemoryBarrier (GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT)`). You need to make sure that `glMapBufferRange (...)` is not evaluated until ***after*** your compute shader runs to ensure visibility, and the only way the GL API guarantees this is if you place that memory barrier before you map your buffer.

Comment: ahh I see.. :) Thanks, I thought it was the shader one. let me try that quickly.

Comment: So I tried that. Now I see the first element of the array updating, but I think the rest of them are staggered indicating that the padding is still not correct somehow. Any idea ? I have the edited structures. One more thing, "Structure alignment is the same as the
alignment for the biggest structure
member, *where three-component
vectors are not rounded up to the size of
four-component vectors*. Each structure
will start on this alignment, and its size
will be the space needed by its
members, according to the previous
rules, rounded up to a multiple of the
structure alignment.

Comment: `std430` is not supposed to require this, but you might try ensuring that the end of the struct is aligned to a 4N boundary. The primary difference between `std140` and `std430` is the behavior with respect to alignment of structs in an *array*. I think I was a little unclear in a comment earlier. These boundaries are not measured in bytes, but rather machine units. A machine unit is basically the size of the simplest scalar type (which is 32-bit in GLSL). So if something needs to be aligned to 4N, that means 4*4 = 16-byte boundary.

Comment: It finally worked. So I had to add 2 padding elements to the end of it to make it aligned to the size of vec4. So the final understanding is that in std430, since I used a vec4, the structure will be aligned on the boundary of vec4.